# What's the difference between these two regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-group, backreference

**The short and immediate version of the question is: Why are these two regex different? i.e.,**

`href=(['"]).+?\1`

vs

`href=(['"]).+?['"]` or `href=(['"]).+?(['"])`

---

I am practicing regex on this site and I am trying to solve this level

http://play.inginf.units.it/#/level/6

I am posting the entire content here in case the site goes down in future.

```
           <tr>
                          <a href="javascript:openurl('/Xplore/accessinfo.jsp')" class="topUnderlineLinks">
                                            <A href="/iel5/4235/4079606/04079617.pdf?tp=&arnumber=4079617&isnumber=4079606" class="bodyCopy">PDF</A>(3141 KB)&nbsp;
                        <A href='/xpl/RecentCon.jsp?punumber=10417'>Evolutionary Computation, 2005. The 2005 IEEE Congress on</A><br>
                <td width="33%" ><div align="right"> <a href="/xplorehelp/Help_start.html#Help_searchresults.html" class="subNavLinks" target="blank">Help</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/xpl/contactus.jsp" class="subNavLinks">Contact
Kimya ile ilgili çeþitli temel referans
<a href="http://search.epnet.com/login.asp?profile=web&amp;defaultdb=geh"
<a href="http://iimpft.chadwyck.com/" target="_parent">International
<a href="standartlar.html#tse" target="_parent">NFPA Standartlarý</a>
<a href="http://www.gutenberg.org/" target="_parent">Project Gutenberg</a>
<a href="http://proquestcombo.safaribooksonline.com/?portal=proquestcombo&amp;uicode=istanbultek"
<a href="http://www.scitation.org" target="_parent">Scitation</a>
dergilerin listesini görmek için <a href="/online/aip.html">bu yolu</a>
<a href="http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/journalfinder.html"
               <td width="46%"><a href="/xpl/periodicals.jsp" class="dropDownNav" accesskey="j">Journals &amp; Magazines
               <td><a href="http://www.ieee.org/products/onlinepubs/resources/XploreTutorial.pdf" class="dropDownNav">IEEE Xplore Demo</a></td>
                          &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/xpl/tocalerts_signup.jsp" class="topUnderlineLinks">Alerts</a>
                        <A href='/xpl/RecentCon.jsp?punumber=10417'>Evolutionary Computation, 2005. The 2005 IEEE Congress on</A><br>
                                    <a href="/search/srchabstract.jsp?arnumber=1554748&isnumber=33079&punumber=10417&k2dockey=1554748@ieeecnfs&query=%28+grammatical+evolution%3Cin%3Eti+%29&pos=9" class="bodyCopy">Abstract</a>
                                          <td><a href="history.jsp">View Session History</a></td>
                                          <td><a href="advsearch.jsp">New Search</a></td>
<a href="http://web5s.silverplatter.com/webspirs/start.ws?customer=kaynak"
<a href="standartlar.html#tse">Türk Standartlarý</a>
<a href="http://isiknowledge.com" target="_parent">Web of Science</a>
<a href='deneme.html#bg'>Butler Group </a>veritabanýna 31 Mart 2007 tarihine kadar deneme eriþimi alýnmýþtýr. &nbsp;<span class="tarih">(19.03.2007)</span> 
<a href='deneme.html#ps'>Productscan</a> veritabanýna 31 Mart 2007 tarihine kadar deneme eriþimi alýnmýþtýr. &nbsp;<span class="tarih">(19.03.2007)</span>
```

I am supposed to match text like this

`href="history.jsp"`

That is I need to match any href in the above text.

Now according to [Solutions](https://gist.github.com/pavi2410/d7a6b038ff7d1386ea9dbf3bb5aa6b48), it seems like the answer for this is `href=(['"]).+?\1`

But that last backreference, if I don't use it and repeat the regex group(I hope parenthesis is called group, correct me if I am wrong), why am I getting different results? That is if I use this I am getting wrong results. `href=(['"]).+?['"]` or `href=(['"]).+?(['"])`

Comment: @Ivar Thanks, Ivar. Actually I just checked that question. In fact I posted a comment there before asking this question since I wasn't able to figure this out just by looking at the definition of backreference.

Comment: I was about to add an additional comment to explain it for your use case, but since you already received an answer it wouldn't add much value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backreference has to match the same thing that the capture group matched. So the first regexp will match

```
"abcd"
```

or

```
'abcd'
```

The second version doesn't link the two ends of the match, so it will match the following as well:

```
"abcd'
```

or

```
'abcd"
```

So the version with the back-reference only matches a string surrounded by the same types of quotes.

This difference is important if you have embedded quotes in a string, e.g.

```
some text "<div id='foo'>" more text
```

The version with the back-reference will match `"<div id='foo'>"`, but the version without the back-reference will match `"<div id='`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes perfect sense. I can now see the advantage of backreference here since it remembers(or has memory) of what was captured before that is either a single quote or a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

The regex snippet `(['"]).+?\1` captures the opening quote with `(...)`, and uses a back-reference to use it later on with `\1`. That means that `'xyzzy'` or `"plugh"` will match but *not* `'twisty"`.

That's probably the correct form since, with `(['"]).+?['"]`, it can open and close with either quote.

---

As an aside, there's little point capturing the groups in your latter expression, unless you're going to use them in the code somehow. If you capture *both,* you could check to ensure they're identical but that's probably best handled by the use of the back-reference version.

In other words, if you wanted to allow something like `'twisty"`, all you need is `['"].+?['"]`.

Comment: Wow thanks, I understand now. Makes perfect sense.